# How do I access request in classes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Not sure if it's possible. Say, I have the following application:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    C.m
end

def f
    request.url
end

class C
    def self.m
        f
    end
end
```

Apparently, it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work without changing `C` class?

**UPD** But one might change the way `f` is called.

Comment: @UriAgassi wrong, this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the request object down:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  C.m(request)
end

def f(request)
  request.url
end

class C
  def self.m(request)
    f(request)
  end
end
```

Comment: That what I was trying to avoid. Hence the condition that one can't change the `C` class except for the `f` call itself.

Comment: I believe there is no other way, due to lexical scoping.